# leer puerto RS-232 de bascula ¿PHP o Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Hola necesito leer el peso de una bascula digital he visto que algunos intentan desde php pero php es del lado del servidor como podria hacer esto desde el lado del cliente talves con jquery o de q manera

Comment: pudiste solucionar, como lo hiciste?

Answer (score 2):

Hola actualmente desde javascript no es posible realizar esto,

Lo que si es posible es que mediante javascript utilices websockets:

https://www.websocket.org/echo.html

estos websockets se pueden conectar a una aplicación de escritorio, en la aplicación de escritorio puedes realizar la conexión al puerto de la bascula.

saludos.